# UIBarButton added to UINavigationItem not showing up

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a bar button to my iOS app and can't get it to show up. I can see the bar in the Navigation Item's view hierarchy by setting a breakpoint. If it helps, I chose 'Embed Navigation Controller'. Any idea what's going on?

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(choosePreferredTerm:)];
[self.navItem setRightBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```

Here is the connection in IB

[image: Interface Builder]

This is what the embedded Navigation Controller looks like:
[image]
This is what it looks like on the sim:
[image: Simulator]

Comment: where is your navigation controller you have defined?

Comment: did u used navigationbar or controller it is not showing into ur image or it may be hidden by you.if it is hidden .show it

Comment: The navigation controller is not hooked up in IB. I chose the embed in Navigation Controller option. I only have an outlet to the navigation item. Is this not correct?


@kamaleshkumaryadav - I added a new image that helps clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rather than using custom outlet "navItem" also insure your application has a navigation controller in place

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried this as well. Also tried self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. No luck :(